# Unity SpriteShape Material with ShaderGraph

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Disclaimer: I know this is not a complete coding question, but since I access and modify the shaders via code, this post fits here IMHO.

**What I've done so far** in the context of a 2D game: I'm using the [SpriteShapes](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.spriteshape@3.0/manual/index.html) for the grounds as well as the fog in a game. Since it's a bit boring to only use simple sprites for fog, I've tried implementing a shader for this (with the new ShaderGraph). I've played a bit around with shaders in the past and also the fog shader implemented for this is working fine with "normal"2D sprites.

**What are the issues:**

1. The coordinates of the fill material seem to bit different to to coordinates of the edge material. Isn't there a way to only use the global coordinate system? I created a workaround to use a complete transparent material for the edges. With the same material the issue is displayed in the screenshot:
   [image: Different coordinates regarding fill and edge material]
2. I want to fade out the texture when it's getting closer to the edge. I acchieved this for simple textures, but I wonder how this can be acchieved according to the actual SpriteShape border. The following screenshot is using a texture that is fadind out at the outer edges, but that is a square and not the actual sprite shape shape:
   [image]

Any help appreciated according to these two problems. I just found simple solutions for 2D sprites, but nothing related to shaders and spriteshapes. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm also trying to create a shader that fades the edge of the sprite shape based on the SpriteShape border.

Comment: @Edvard-D Sorry, no I never get this working. I ended up with the non transparent version and added some simple sprites/shapes/shader to add additional fog effects.